# Command "eport" not found. Try epost from deb

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, terminal

I recently installed a few files in the terminal for Linux for the first time and during the process I misstyped `export` as `eport`. Now every time I open the terminal i get this message above where I can type in commands.

```
Command 'eport' not found, did you mean:
    command 'epost' from deb ncbi-entrez-direct
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>

user@usersLaptop:~$
```

For clarification I am using bash. After closing and re-opening the terminal this error message is always at the top. How do I go about fixing the typo that I made if that is the issue?

Comment: If you have a typo in one of your startup files, you need to fix it.

Comment: I edited the post adding, I hope, some clarification. @KamilMaciorowski .

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would I fix typos in the startup files? @tripleee

Comment: If you can [edit] your question to clarify what you changed and how it's wrong, it will be easy to answer. Without details, it's hard to say more than "find the typo and fix it". Maybe try `grep -Fws eport .[!.]*` in your home directory if you don't know exactly (but then chances are there will be other typos which we can't help you with until you ask about those too).